# jQuery TypeError .offset is undefined

Tags: jquery, wordpress

have been trying to resolve this issue for many hours now and just cant figure it out.

The environment is WordPress I am using a smooth scroll  function that will smooth scroll when I select a link on one page to a location on another page.

the error I am getting is...

TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined

the offending line of code is...

```
  scrollTop: $(elem).offset().top - headerHeight
```

My entire function is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var headerHeight = $('#header-wrap').height(); //When the header position is fixed

$('a').click(function(){
    var hashEle = $(this).attr('href').split('#');
    if (hashEle.length > 1) {
        if (hashEle[1] == 'top') {
            $('body, html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            },800);
        } else {
        jQuery('body, html').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#'+ hashEle[1]).offset().top - headerHeight
        },800);
        }
    };
})
// find element from url
hashname = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
elem = $('#' + hashname);
if(hashname.length > 1) {
    if(hashname == 'top') {
    $('body, html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        },500); 
    } else {
     $('body, html').animate({
            scrollTop: $(elem).offset().top - headerHeight
        },800);
 }
};

 });
```

I am going crazy here, the code works fine but it is creating a conflict with WooCommerce and I would just like it not to throw an error. Can someone tell me why this is causing trouble, sorry for the newbi question!

Comment: First of all, have you included JQuery in your page?

Then... try to debug that elem does actually exist. Try to console.log(elem), and see if the element is defined. Then post here the result :)

Comment: Yes jQuery is included in the top through functions.php and when I type .log(elem) into the chrome console it says that there is a SyntaxError: Unexpected token...

But now that I am looking at it could it be because I left the var out infront of elem =$('#' + hashname); New to jquery and javascript. :)

Comment: Hi, that shouldn't be a problem, it's just to keep the variable into the current scope.
The problem, I guess, is that the value of hashname has some token which cannot be used with the JQuery query selector. Could you please write here what console.log(hashname) returns? That will make us find out.

Comment: Nope that didn't change anything. The way I see $(elem) is it is referenced above as a variable elem = $('#', + hashname); and is then used in the scrollTop function as the specific element to scroll to and .offset().top - headerHeight simply adjusts the stop location to account for the fixed header.

I have changed the line elem = to var elemnt = $('#' + hashname); and the scrollTop to... scrollTop: $(elemnt).offset().top - headerHeight but I am still getting the same issue with the TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined

Comment: We just need to understand what makes the JQuery selector fail, which I think is the value of hashname. We can find it out by calling console.log(hashname) BEFORE you declare elem. Then you should see, in the console, what the value of hashname is and why it makes the selector fail. We're only trying to debug, not to fix :)

Comment: ahhhhh about the console.log(elem) I didnt follow you correctly, sorry, left the console off!

It did find it and it comes in with something expandable

[context: document, selector: "#", jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function, toArray: function…]

Under that though it says that it is undefined

console.log(hashname) turns up nothing and but undefined, could that be because it is only supposed to execute on page load the purpose of this code is to smooth scroll from page a to page b like when you are on page a and click link pageb##location

Comment: Yea it is strange because it is not causing the jquery to fail, this script works very well, it only causes an issue with another script (WooCommerce) and throws that error in the console. When I remove the script that throws the error WooCommerce starts working (the add to cart button).

Comment: Yeah, the script should work, then I'd think that window.location.hash returns an empty string, which obviously causes JQuery to fail. Then, there must be something which makes the URL not to have the # + string you chase. A precedent error in the other script maybe? Do you change the URL programmatically? You should catch the first occurring error to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: I get it and you are right, it is something to do with the hashname. because the string is empty it causes the scrollTop $(elem).offset to fail. But why does this work then lol crazy stuff!! I will need to figure out the hashname more to get this under control.

Answer (score 1):

I may have found out the problem:

- the script works fine
- the hash is wrong!

You said you have ##location in your URL string. If you use:

```
window.location.hash
```

It won't return anything. The right hash should be #location, which is different from ##location.

If you hardcode the hash in your URL and try again you'll see it works. If it doesn't work, then you have some script acting before which causes it (but I don't think so if you're just following a link, which should be worng)

To try it out, then change ##location with #top (or any thing according to your page elements)

Comment: Yea that was a typo :( turns out it had everything to do with the placement of my jQuery and possibly that it was 1.11 I moved it to the head and loaded 1.10.2 and it works perfect. Will have to do some more research on this to get a better answer. Thank s to both of you for your help I love working out problems like this with the community, thans to both of you again!!!!